# How to create a column with a quartile rank?

Tags: r

I have a table called tableOne in R like this:

```
idNum        binaryVariable        salePrice
2               1                    55.56
4               0                    88.33
15              0                     4.45
87              1                    35.77
...            ...                    ...
```

I'd like to take the values produced from: summary(tableOne$salePrice) to create four quartiles by salePrice.  I'd then like to create a column tableOne$quartile with which quartile each rows salePrice is in.  It would look like:

```
idNum        binaryVariable            salePrice      quartile
    2               1                    55.56            3
    4               0                    88.33            4
    15              0                     4.45            1
    87              1                    35.77            2 
    ...            ...                    ...            ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This should do it:

```
tableOne <- within(tableOne, quartile <- as.integer(cut(salesPrice, quantile(salesPrice, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE)))
```

...Some details:

The `within` function is great for calculating new columns. You don't have to refer to columns as 
`tableOne$salesPrice` etc.

```
tableOne <- within(tableOne, quartile <- <<<some expression>>>)
```

The `quantile` function calculates the quantiles (or in your case, quartiles). `0:4/4` evaluates to `c(0, 0.25, 0.50, 0.75, 1)`.

Finally the `cut` function splits your data into those quartiles. But you get a `factor` with weird names, so `as.integer` turns it into groups `1,2,3,4`.

Try `?within` etc to learn more about the functions mentioned here...

Comment: instead of changing to `integer`, it is also posible to use `label` option of `cut`. Using the very quartile (or quantile) as the label makes it explicit the limits of the classes. In this case, `..., label = quantile(salesPrice, probs=0:4/4)[2:5]`. It is necessary to take off one label (the zero).

Answer (score 9):

A data.table approach

```
    library(data.table)
    tableOne <- setDT(tableOne)[, quartile := cut(salesPrice, quantile(salesPrice, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE)]
```

Answer (score 9):

With dplyr you could use the ntile function:

```
ntile(x, n)


tableOne$quartile <- ntile(tableOne$salesPrice, 4)
```

This will add a column to the table assigning a quantile based on n to each row with the price quantile it is in.

Note: This method starts with the lower values at 1 and works upwards from there.

Comment: `ntile()` does not separate into quartile ranks, it divides the data into `n` equally sized buckets.

Answer (score 6):

Setting the parameter `labels=FALSE` in `cut()` returns category names as integers. See `?cut`

```
tableOne <- within(tableOne, quartile <- cut(salesPrice, quantile(salesPrice, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE, labels=FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script

```
tableOne$Quartile<-ifelse(tableOne$salesPrice<=quantile(tableOne$salesPrice,c(0.25)),1,
                           ifelse(tableOne$salesPrice<=quantile(tableOne$salesPrice,c(0.5)),2,
                                  ifelse(tableOne$salesPrice<=quantile(tableOne$salesPrice,c(0.75)),3,
                                         ifelse(tableOne$salesPrice<=quantile(tableOne$salesPrice,c(1)),4,NA))))
```

Comment: While this works, it is inefficient because it recalculates the quantiles for each level. Also it obviously doesn't scale up well... if you wanted deciles instead of quartiles it would be annoying. If you wanted percentiles instead of quartiles it would be a big mess.

Answer (score 0):

using package [`cutr`](https://github.com/moodymudskipper/cutr) we can do :

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/cutr")
library(cutr)
df$quartile <- smart_cut(df$salePrice, 4, "g", output = "numeric")
#   idNum binaryVariable salePrice quartile
# 1     2              1     55.56        3
# 2     4              0     88.33        4
# 3    15              0      4.45        1
# 4    87              1     35.77        2
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code creates an ntile group vector:

```
qgroup = function(numvec, n = 4){

    qtile = quantile(numvec, probs = seq(0, 1, 1/n))
    out = sapply(numvec, function(x) sum(x >= qtile[-(n+1)]))

    return(out)
}
```