# get quartile for every row in matrix R

Tags: r

I have a 46175*741 matrix. I want to get quartiles for every row. Based on this question ([How to create a column with a quartile rank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508229/how-to-create-a-column-with-a-quartile-rank)), 
I tried :

```
dat_quartiles <- apply(t(dat) , 1, function(x) within(x, as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE))))
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in UseMethod("within") : no applicable method for 'within' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

Where exactly am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be reading too much into what you are trying to do, but this owuld be the simplest way that I can think of for returning the quartiles of each row in a matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(rnorm(1000), 100,10)
apply(mat, 1, quantile)
```

To assign the number of the quantile:

```
quantfun <- function(x) as.integer(cut(x, quantile(x, probs=0:4/4), include.lowest=TRUE))
apply(mat, 1, quantfun)
```

Comment: Yes, I had done it like that first, but I want it to tell me if its first quartile or second etc instead of the exact numbers for each row.

Comment: @pepsimax - should work now. If you are just interested in the resulting values, then you don't need `within`.

Comment: I had non unique values so to get your code to work, I had to use unique(quantile...). Thanks a million though Marc! it's not the first time you've helped me :)