# how to create a dummy variable for value in top quartile (or other quantile)

Tags: r, dplyr

Simple R question here, and a little similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508229/how-to-create-a-column-with-a-quartile-rank) but I couldn't figure out how to adapt the insights from there into my setting.

I have a dataframe with relative quality rankings from several firms, e.g.

```
Firm    Quality
  A        4
  B        5
  C        2
  D        0
```

I want to add a third column that is 1 if quality is at or above the 50th percentile (and 0 otherwise), and a fourth column that is 1 if quality is at or above the 75th percentile (and 0 otherwise). Solutions like the one linked above seem to rely on `cut()` and `within()`; they are relatively old though, pre-dplyr, and I'm wondering if there's a good way to use `summarise()` and the dplyr summary functions to do this in a way that is more intuitive (at least for this newbie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ronak's answer is perfectly fine, but just for the fun of it, a fully `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Above50 = as.numeric(ntile(Quality, 2)==2), 
         Above75 = as.numeric(ntile(Quality, 4)==4))
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Above50 = as.numeric(Quality >= quantile(Quality, 0.5)), 
         Above75 = as.numeric(Quality >= quantile(Quality, 0.75)))


#  Firm Quality Above50 Above75
#1    A       4       1       0
#2    B       5       1       1
#3    C       2       0       0
#4    D       0       0       0
```