# R: Using DPLYR to Calculate Quantiles?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

var1 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var2 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var3 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var4 = rnorm(10000, 100,100)
var5 <- factor(sample(c("Yes", "No"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6)))
var6 <- factor(sample(c("Yes", "No"), 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6)))

my_data = data.frame( var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6)
```

I am trying to run the following code:

```
my_data %>%
    group_by(var5) %>%
    mutate(col1 = ntile(var1, 5))
```

**This code works on this sample dataset, but on my real dataset -  I always get the following error:**

```
Error: Column 'col1' must be length xyz (the group size) or one, not abc
```

What kind of strategies can I use to avoid this error?

Thanks!

**References:**

- [How to create a column with a quartile rank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508229/how-to-create-a-column-with-a-quartile-rank)
- https://www.statology.org/r-quantile-by-group/

Comment: It will be hard for users to help you if you don't provide a reproduceable example of the error.

Comment: Can you show your `packageVersion("dplyr")`?  Also, if you can subset your original data and get the same error, it may be better to get the `dput(yoursubsetdata)` (20-30 rows max)

Comment: Can you create an example that gives the error

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using purrr::safely to construct a version of ntile that wont stop/quit when facing an error, make it output something distinctive (-Inf)
Try and identify where and why the error is occurring.

```
safe_ntile <- purrr::safely(function(x)ntile(x,5),
                            otherwise = -Inf,
                            quiet = TRUE)

my_data %>%
  group_by(var5) %>%
  mutate(res = safe_ntile(var1)$result)
```

Assuming you are struggling to pin the issue down because you have many groups, and not simply 2 as in your example ? The method proposed about should let you at least find the group of interest.