# Learning How to Calculate "Nested Percentiles" Within SQL

Tags: sql, r

In a previous question ([R: Calculating Proportions Based on Nested Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027090/r-calculating-proportions-based-on-nested-groups)), I learned how to calculate "nested percentiles" in R.

For example, suppose I have this data:

```
set.seed(123)
library(dplyr)

Patient_ID = 1:5000
gender <- c("Male","Female")
gender <- sample(gender, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.45, 0.55))
Gender <- as.factor(gender)


status <- c("Immigrant","Citizen")
status <- sample(status, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))
Status  <- as.factor(status )

Height = rnorm(5000, 150, 10)
Weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)
Hospital_Visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)

################

disease <- c("Yes","No")
disease <- sample(disease, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))
Disease <- as.factor(disease)

###################
my_data = data.frame(Patient_ID, Gender, Status, Height, Weight, Hospital_Visits, Disease)

  Patient_ID Gender    Status   Height    Weight Hospital_Visits Disease
1          1 Female   Citizen 145.0583 113.70725               1      No
2          2   Male Immigrant 161.2759  88.33188              18      No
3          3 Female Immigrant 138.5305  99.26961               6     Yes
4          4   Male   Citizen 164.8102  84.31848              12      No
5          5   Male   Citizen 159.1619  92.25090              12     Yes
6          6 Female   Citizen 153.3513 101.31986              11     Yes
```

I can now use this R code (modified from the answer [R: Calculating Proportions Based on Nested Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75027090/r-calculating-proportions-based-on-nested-groups) ) to calculate **"nested percentiles"**:

```
 final = my_data %>%
    group_by(Gender, Status) %>%
    mutate(
        Height_ntile = ntile(Height, 3),
        Height_range = paste(sprintf("%.2f", min(Height)), sprintf("%.2f", max(Height)), sep = "-")
    ) %>%
    group_by(Height_ntile, Height_range, .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(
        Weight_ntile = ntile(Weight, 3),
        Weight_range = paste(sprintf("%.2f", min(Weight)), sprintf("%.2f", max(Weight)), sep = "-")
    ) %>%
    group_by(Weight_ntile, Weight_range, .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(
        Hospital_Visits_ntile = ntile(Hospital_Visits, 3),
        Hospital_range = paste(min(Hospital_Visits), max(Hospital_Visits), sep = "-")
    ) %>%
    group_by(Hospital_Visits_ntile, Hospital_range, .add = TRUE) %>%
    summarize(
        percent_disease = mean(Disease == "Yes"),
        count = n(),
        .groups = "drop"
    )
```

The results look something like this - we can see the how different "nested" groups of hospital patients are observed to have a certain disease:

```
 Gender Status  Height_ntile Height_range  Weight_ntile Weight_range Hospital_Visits_ntile Hospital_range percent_disease count
   <fct>  <fct>          <int> <chr>                <int> <chr>                        <int> <chr>                    <dbl> <int>
 1 Female Citizen            1 115.86-188.48            1 58.99-121.02                     1 1-20                     0.319    72
 2 Female Citizen            1 115.86-188.48            1 58.99-121.02                     2 1-20                     0.458    72
 3 Female Citizen            1 115.86-188.48            1 58.99-121.02                     3 1-20                     0.310    71
```

**My Problem:** I am now trying to learn how I can write a similar procedure in SQL (**Netezza**).

I first simulated a local connection within R and uploaded this dataset:

```
library(DBI)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = ":memory:")
copy_to(con, my_data)
```

Then, using the `PERCENTILE()` function available within Netezza SQL, I tried to replicate this R code using a series of CTE's:

```
query1 <- "
WITH height_groups AS (
  SELECT Patient_ID,
         Gender,
         Status,
         Height,
         Weight,
         Hospital_Visits,
         Disease,
         NTILE(3) OVER (PARTITION BY Gender, Status ORDER BY Height) AS Height_ntile
  FROM my_data
),
weight_groups AS (
  SELECT Patient_ID,
         Gender,
         Status,
         Height,
         Weight,
         Hospital_Visits,
         Disease,
         Height_ntile,
         NTILE(3) OVER (PARTITION BY Gender, Status, Height_ntile ORDER BY Weight) AS Weight_ntile
  FROM height_groups
),
hospital_visits_groups AS (
  SELECT Patient_ID,
         Gender,
         Status,
         Height,
         Weight,
         Hospital_Visits,
         Disease,
         Height_ntile,
         Weight_ntile,
         NTILE(3) OVER (PARTITION BY Gender, Status, Height_ntile, Weight_ntile ORDER BY Hospital_Visits) AS Hospital_Visits_ntile
  FROM weight_groups
)
SELECT Gender, 
       Status, 
       Height_ntile, 
       Weight_ntile, 
       Hospital_Visits_ntile, 
       AVG(CASE WHEN Disease = 'Yes' THEN 1.0 ELSE 0.0 END) AS percent_disease, 
       COUNT(*) AS count
FROM hospital_visits_groups
GROUP BY Gender, Status, Height_ntile, Weight_ntile, Hospital_Visits_ntile;
"

result <- dbGetQuery(con, query1)
```

**My Question:** While the SQL code seems to have run, I am not sure if I am approaching this problem correctly. For example, I am not sure how I can add columns to represent the min/max ranges for the variables being binned using the percentile functions. I also not sure if certain "hospital patients" are being double counted (e.g. assigned to multiple groups) or if some of the percentile ranges might be "overlapping" (e.g. height_range_1: 155-174, height_range_2: 150-183).

**Can someone please help me correct this Netezza SQL query?**

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a working dplyr pipe being stored into `final`, perhaps instead of starting with `my_data` you start with `tbl(con, "my_data")` (assuming that is also the name of the SQL table), and then end it with [`%>% show_query()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/explain.html). It is not always the most awesome-looking, but at least it will give you as literal a translation from dplyr-speak to SQL-speak as can be reasonable done. (It may also help to reduce the complexity of the pipe a little just to reduce the complexity of the SQL, to discover the code patterns.)

Comment: @ r2evansL thank you for your reply! I will try to use the show_query() function and see if this can give me any suggestions. thanks!